# Assigning Known/non-random Variables to Turtles and placing turtles in defined positions

Tags: netlogo

Is there a way to create turtles in a NetLogo world, assign them to specific patches so as to achieve some geographic arrangement AND also assign the turtles known values for their variables.

Let's say I want to represent cities as turtles and I want to locate the cities on the NL world with some relation to reality e.g. New York in North east corner, LA in far west corner.  I also want to then assign specific variables that I  know for each city to the turtles that represent the cities e.g New York has unemployment rate of 85, LA has 12% unemployment, etc.. After which I want to execute my model

How would I go about this in NL?

Thank you!

Comment: This seems like about six questions in one. Why not take a stab at the first step in this, and post your code if you get stuck?

Comment: Well, I am quite confused.  My desire was to implement this using the GIS extension, but the NL guide was not very helpful.  I was able to load the map and I see it in the NL world screen, but how to proceed from there to make the states I see in the map become states I do not know.  So this question is really trying to find a work around to my preferred GIS solution.

Comment: This post shows what I really want to do:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397271/making-states-in-a-gis-file-turtles-in-netlogo

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you'll need a file with the data. 
Say your file looks like:

```
NY -15 15
MA 15 15
NM 0 12
```

Where the first two letters are the `name` of the state.
Next two set of numbers are desired coordinates in the NL world.

You can save that in a file and read it through NL code.
You can use more than just 3 columns if you want to save more already known-variables.

You might want to use [file-read-line](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/file-read-line.html).